# same query with order clause, same dataset, but different result

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by

I was testing my application(an ERP system) by programming a tester that will do a fixed scenario of 30 steps of things like this

```
//pseudo code(PHP)
public function runScenario1Test(){
    V2_1Tester::resetDatabase();
    V2_1Tester::insert60Companies();
    V2_1Tester::insert2000Items();
    V2_1Tester::insert100Purchases();
    V2_1Tester::insert100Sales();

    //do some other stuff

    V2_1Tester:checkResults();
}
```

Although every time I run the test of the same code, same data, **all inputs were the same**, I was getting different results sometimes!!!

My head was going to blow up, and after 4 days of investigations, tears, and even bad database dreams by night, it turns out that the bug was in a query that returns different results sometimes. It is something like this

```
+-----+--------------+-----------+------+--------+
| ID  |     date     | direction | col3 |  col4  |
+-----+--------------+-----------+------+--------+
|  1  |  2018-03-03  |     in    |   6  | 100.50 |
|  2  |  2018-03-03  |     in    |   6  | 350.75 |
+-----+--------------+-----------+------+--------+
-- more ~ 3000 rows

$query = "SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY date, direction, col3";
```

this query sometimes returns 1 then 2 and some other times 2 then 1.

I fixed the query by adding additional level for ordering `ID`

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY date, direction, col3, ID";
```

But I don't understand why MySQL behaves like this ?, In other words **what are the rules that MySQL will follow for the rows that are the same for all order-by columns ? and why it is changing ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SQL, `order by` is not stable.  That means that when the keys are the same, the ordering can be in any order.

This is actually obvious.  SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  There is no ordering unless a column specifies the ordering.

So, you have done the right thing by including the `id` as the final key.  This ensures that the order will be well-defined because there are no duplicate keys.